# Find minExam in the function

Tags: c++, min

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this function. I need to find the nimimum exam in the function.

```
  void findMinExam( int exam1, int exam2, int exam3, int& minExam)
//***************************************************************************************
//Purpose: Determine the lowest exam score.
//Input: exam1, exam2, exam3, minExam
//Precondition: exam1, exam2, exam3, minExam have values and are valid.
//Output: int.
//Post condition: This function shows the lowest exam.
//Note: None. 
//****************************************************************************************
{
  if (exam1 < minExam)
     {
     minExam = exam1;
     }
  if (exam2 < minExam)
     {
     minExam = exam2;
     }
  if (exam3 < minExam)
     {
     minExam = exam3;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your code has a huge conceptual problem: What is the value of `minExam` when the function is called? I suggest simply to return by value or if this is indeed necessary, set `minExam` to `exam1` in the beginning.

Comment: You should set `minExam` to the maximum exam score in the main program.

Comment: Your function can effectively be replaced with `int minExam = std::min({exam1, exam2, exam3});`

Comment: @pmr: why? minExam is an input, too, as per documentation!

Comment: @chris: it could be, `int minExam = std::min({exam1, exam2, exam3, minExam});` depending on the exact use case, but more like it based on the documentation. Also, it assumes the OP has C++11 support.

Comment: Lol.. If you're in a good mood and you want to roll your own, you can always do: `minExam = exam1 < (exam2 < exam3 ? (exam2 < minExam ? exam2 : minExam) : (exam3 < minExam ? exam3 : minExam)) ? exam1 : (exam2 < exam3 ? (exam2 < minExam ? exam2 : minExam) : (exam3 < minExam ? exam3 : minExam));`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, there is no behavior problem with your code... just API quirks, but your explanation of the issue may be incorrect.

Either way, if you have C++11 support, you could simply write this instead of your own hand-crafted function, as pointed out in the comments:

```
minExam = std::min({exam1, exam2, exam3, minExam});
```